Variables set inside the rcfile are NOT accessible through Python
I've a shell script and a python script organized as follows (CAN NOT change the directory structure):
~
├── a.py
├── b
    └── c.sh

The MWEs are as follows:
c.sh
#!/bin/sh
rcfile=$(mktemp)
export TEST1='hello'
cat <<-EOF > ${rcfile}
    export TEST2='world'
EOF
${SHELL} --rcfile ${rcfile}
rm -f ${rcfile}

a.py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen('./c.sh', cwd='./b', stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(b'echo $TEST1\necho $TEST2\nexit')

When I execute the shell script c.sh, it shows both the variables as expected.

However, when executed from the python script a.py, the inner variable i.e. TEST2 is not set.

I CAN NOT modify the shell script.
Is there a way to access both the variables TEST1 and TEST2 from the python script?

You are executing rcfile in a subshell.  The variable it defines necessarily vanishes when that subshell exits.  You would need to do source ./rcfile to execute the definition in the context of c.sh, so that you could see the variable.  (Since you apparently can't modify c.sh, you'd have to put that command in the string you pass to .communicate().)

Please don't post pictures of text; instead post the text itself and use code formatting.

@jasonharper the problem here is that the rcfile is being generated in run-time using the command mktemp. I think I should've mentioned that in the code examples.

@jasonharper But the  commands sent with p.communicate() are being executed in the subshell, aren't they?

The problem is that --rcfile is only used by interactive shells. Since the shell's stdin is a pipe rather than a terminal when you run it from python, it ignores that option.

Use pexpect instead of subprocess, then it will use a pty instead of a pipe.

You can set variables directly from Python.
subprocess.run(
    'echo "$TEST2"',
    shell=True, check=True,
    env={"TEST2": "foo"})

Yes, probably prefer subprocess.run over bare Popen when you can, though if you need the shell to run in parallel with your Python script, that's not possible.

I have tried to use pexpect and still missing the second value ($TEST2). I suspect this is a problem with buffering. In the mean time, I came up with a work around: while you cannot modify the shell script; you can modify a copy of it. For my solution, I will make a copy, modify the line which runs the shell so that it will

Source the rcfile
echo TEST1, TEST2

Code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pathlib
import subprocess

# Duplicate c.sh and modify the SHELL line
original_script = pathlib.Path("./b/c.sh")
modified_script = original_script.with_stem("c-copy")
content = original_script.read_text().splitlines()

with open(modified_script, "w", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    for line in content:
        if line.startswith("${SHELL}"):
            line = ". ${rcfile}\necho TEST1=$TEST1\necho TEST2=$TEST2"
        stream.write(f"{line}\n")

# Run
modified_script.chmod(0o777)
process = subprocess.run(
    ["./b/c-copy.sh"],
    text=True,
    capture_output=True,
)

# Clean up
modified_script.unlink()

# Parse output and print. Assume that the shell script might produce
# other output, so we only grab lines with starts with "TEST"
shell_vars = dict(
    line.split("=") for line in process.stdout.splitlines()
    if line.startswith("TEST")
)
print(shell_vars)

Output:
{'TEST1': 'hello', 'TEST2': 'world'}

I tested this in Fedora 40 and Python 3.12.4.
